# How to start Android test unit from command line

Tags: android, unit-testing, adb

Im writing automatic test for my program. I have completed writing it on Android. However, now I want to write a script to run it from command line adb shell. Do you know how to do it? As I test many components of my program, running it from script will save lots of my effort.

Thanks.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.wsandroid.test"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.wsandroid" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsCommand), there is a set of commands to run one single unit test:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w \
 -e class com.android.samples.AllTests \
 com.android.samples.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

You will specify your class-name where the class label is in the above command-line sequence.